# How to call method in gui (application) thread from method in non-gui thread?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread, qtimer

I have a potentially long-running task (serialise a document) which I don't want to run in the Gui thread. At the end of that task I want to update various visual aspects of the UI (menu enablement, etc.).

I had assumed that `QTimer.singleShot()` was the way to go, and that the method it runs would always execute in the Gui thread. But this turns out not to be so: if you call it in a non-Gui thread, its invoked method runs in a non-Gui thread (the same one).

I have double-checked this on my OS (W10). If you find that this is not the case on yours I'd be interested to hear about it.

I've actually created a decorator to check that every method in my app runs in the right thread (Gui or non-Gui). There are one or two where the parameter is `None` (= can be either) but these are very few. The method which updates the UI elements MUST be called in the Gui thread.

I can of course do this by creating a new signal and firing that. Is there not a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: I'd recommend to take a look on the `self.thread_pool = QThreadPool(); self.thread_pool.start(self.worker)` with the worker and the `pyqtSignal` from the `PyQt5.QtCore` that will be sent to the worker from the gui.

Comment: Not sure you've got the gist of the question: I need to invoke a method in the GUI thread **from** another run in a non-GUI thread, not the other way round (which is indeed trivial). Also, again as I wrote, I'm wondering whether there is a solution which, precisely, does NOT use a signal! Again, using a signal to do this is very obvious.

Comment: @mikerodent it all depends on what that method should do. If it interacts with UI elements, then there's no other choice than using signals. You could create a custom QEvent and use `QApplication.postEvent()`, but that wouldn't change that much, nor would be a "simpler" solution than using signals. The real question is: why you don't want to use signals?

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. I'm fine about using a signal... it's just that I had assumed initially that `QTimer.singleShot` provided a signal-free solution, and that seeing that that is not the case, I might have hoped that there might be something equivalent to `executor.submit(...)` but which runs the submitted function in the Gui thread. It's good to have the input of an expert, so after you have spoken I think I'll just use a signal!

Comment: @mikerodent QTimer is a QObject, and works in the same way (the target function is directly connected to its `timeout` signal), but you have to be careful: a timer can be only started and stopped from the thread in which it was created (which is fine for QTimer.singleShot), but you must be sure to directly call a function in the other thread (so, no lambda), as Qt requires to use thread affinity to know *if* the "target" is in a different thread (and eventually use a queued connection), which lambda doesn't allow, because Qt (nor python) has no way to know what the lambda does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this appears to be No (see Musicamante's comments).

I'm not sure whether to delete this question. I think it clarifies things for me.